# Класс прямоугольников и его методы

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Прохожу все тесты, указанные в примерах. Но последний тест, который не указан - выдаёт ошибку.

> Разработайте класс Rectangle.
>
> При инициализации класс принимает два кортежа рациональных координат
> противоположных углов прямоугольника (со сторонами параллельными осям
> координат).
>
> get_pos() — возвращает координаты верхнего левого угла в виде кортежа;
>
> get_size() — возвращает размеры в виде кортежа;
>
> move(dx, dy) — изменяет положение на заданные значения;
>
> resize(width, height) — изменяет размер (положение верхнего левого угла остаётся неизменным)
>
> Примечание
> Ваше решение должно содержать только классы и функции.
> В решении не должно быть вызовов инициализации требуемых классов.
> Все результаты вычислений нужно округлить до сотых.
>
> Пример 1
>
> Ввод
> rect = Rectangle((3.2, -4.3), (7.52, 3.14))
>
> print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
>
> rect.move(1.32, -5)
>
> print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
>
> Вывод
>
> (3.2, 3.14) (4.32, 7.44)
>
> (4.52, -1.86) (4.32, 7.44)
>
> Пример 2
>
> Ввод
>
> rect = Rectangle((7.52, -4.3), (3.2, 3.14))
>
> print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
>
> rect.resize(23.5, 11.3)
>
> print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
>
> Вывод
>
> (3.2, 3.14) (4.32, 7.44)
>
> (3.2, 3.14) (23.5, 11.3)

Мой код, ООП только начинаю проходить, самостоятельно. Примеры здесь внесла для проверки. В тестирующую систему отправляю без них.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, coord_1=(0., 0.), coord_2=(0., 0.)):
        self.coord_1 = coord_1
        self.coord_2 = coord_2
        if self.coord_2[0] > self.coord_1[0]:
            self.top_left = self.coord_1[0], self.coord_2[1]
            self.btm_rigth = self.coord_2[0], self.coord_1[1]
        elif self.coord_2[1] > self.coord_1[1]:
            self.top_left = self.coord_2
            self.btm_rigth = self.coord_1
        else:
            self.top_left = self.coord_1
            self.btm_rigth = self.coord_2
        self.width = abs(self.btm_rigth[0] - self.top_left[0])
        self.height = abs(self.btm_rigth[1]) + abs(self.top_left[1])

    def perimeter(self):
        return round((self.width + self.height) * 2, 2)

    def area(self):
        return round(self.width * self.height, 2)

    def get_pos(self):
        return self.top_left

    def get_size(self):
        return round(self.width, 2), round(self.height, 2)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.top_left = list(self.top_left)
        self.btm_rigth = list(self.btm_rigth)
        self.top_left = (round((self.top_left[0] + dx), 2),
                         round((self.top_left[1] + dy), 2))
        self.btm_rigth = (round((self.btm_rigth[0] + dx), 2),
                          round((self.btm_rigth[1] + dy), 2))

    def resize(self, width, height):
        self.btm_rigth = list(self.btm_rigth)
        self.btm_rigth = (self.btm_rigth[0] + self.width - width,
                          self.btm_rigth[1] + self.height - height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


rect = Rectangle((3.2, -4.3), (7.52, 3.14))
print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
rect.move(1.32, -5)
print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())

rect = Rectangle((7.52, -4.3), (3.2, 3.14))
print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
rect.resize(23.5, 11.3)
print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
```

Тест 3. Ответ неверный. Ошибка в программе или неверный алгоритм.

Comment: Тут ошибка: `self.height = abs(self.btm_rigth[1]) + abs(self.top_left[1])`.

Comment: Спасибо! Изменила на: self.height = round(abs(self.top_left[1] - self.btm_rigth[1]), 2) Результат тот же. Тест 3 неверный. Ошибка в программе или неверный алгоритм.

Comment: Поняла, что ошибка скорее всего в методе resize, пытаюсь решить.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш класс `Rectangle` имеет правильную структуру и методы, но есть небольшая ошибка в методе `move`, и вам нужно изменить метод `resize`:

1. Метод `move` должен изменять положение верхнего левого угла, но вы изменяете и верхний левый угол и правый нижний угол. Вам нужно только изменить верхний левый угол.
2. Метод `resize` должен изменить размер, но не должен изменять положение верхнего левого угла. Вам нужно только изменить ширину и высоту.

Вот исправленный код:

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, coord_1=(0., 0.), coord_2=(0., 0.)):
        self.coord_1 = coord_1
        self.coord_2 = coord_2
        if self.coord_2[0] > self.coord_1[0]:
            self.top_left = self.coord_1
            self.btm_rigth = self.coord_2
        else:
            self.top_left = self.coord_2
            self.btm_rigth = self.coord_1
        self.width = abs(self.btm_rigth[0] - self.top_left[0])
        self.height = abs(self.btm_rigth[1] - self.top_left[1])

    def get_pos(self):
        return self.top_left

    def get_size(self):
        return (round(self.width, 2), round(self.height, 2))

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.top_left = (round(self.top_left[0] + dx, 2), round(self.top_left[1] + dy, 2))
        self.btm_rigth = (round(self.btm_rigth[0] + dx, 2), round(self.btm_rigth[1] + dy, 2))

    def resize(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

rect = Rectangle((3.2, -4.3), (7.52, 3.14))
print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
rect.move(1.32, -5)
print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())

rect = Rectangle((7.52, -4.3), (3.2, 3.14))
print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
rect.resize(23.5, 11.3)
print(rect.get_pos(), rect.get_size())
```

Теперь класс `Rectangle` должен работать правильно, и тесты должны проходить без ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, который прошел все тесты

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, coord_1, coord_2):
        self.coord_1 = coord_1
        self.coord_2 = coord_2
        self.top_left = (min(self.coord_1[0], self.coord_2[0]),
                         max(self.coord_1[1], self.coord_2[1]))
        self.btm_rigth = (max(self.coord_1[0], self.coord_2[0]),
                          min(self.coord_1[1], self.coord_2[1]))
        self.width = abs(self.btm_rigth[0] - self.top_left[0])
        self.height = abs(self.btm_rigth[1] - self.top_left[1])

    def perimeter(self):
        return round((self.width + self.height) * 2, 2)

    def area(self):
        return round(self.width * self.height, 2)

    def get_pos(self):
        return self.top_left

    def get_size(self):
        return (round(self.width, 2), round(self.height, 2))

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.top_left = (round(self.top_left[0] + dx, 2),
                         round(self.top_left[1] + dy, 2))
        self.btm_rigth = (round(self.btm_rigth[0] + dx, 2),
                          round(self.btm_rigth[1] + dy, 2))

    def resize(self, width, height):
        self.btm_rigth = (round(self.top_left[0] + width, 2),
                          round(self.top_left[1] - height, 2))
        self.width = round(width, 2)
        self.height = round(height, 2)
```

изменила поле верхнего левого угла и нижнего правого, поле высоты; метод `resize`, во всех вычислениях добавила округление

Comment: Ответ выше не прошёл тесты? Я думаю ваш ответ нужно удалить так как он опубликован после ответа который дан за день до вашего.

Comment: Ответ выше не прошел тесты, там есть ошибки в первом методе. Я не знаю как удалить этот ответ.